# Android Accent Color

Tags: android, android-activity, android-styles

I am having issue with accent color. Sometimes it appear on all screens. My accent color is orange in color.

This is my style applied on all activities:

```
 <style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange_color</item>
        <!--Default Text Color -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>

    </style>
```

I have attached image for reference. Toolbar bg is has light blue color, where as the line has light gray color

[image]

Answer (score 4):

set background color in toolbar as below..

```
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

and set `colorPrimary` in style whatever color you want in toolbar.

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

---

final code is :

```
<style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange_color</item>
        <!--Default Text Color -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>

    </style>
```

and toolbar is :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

Comment: changing color of toolbar is not an issue. The problem is that at times everything in my app changes to orange

Comment: I think you set only accent color. you can try by setting up primary color and primary dark color.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try directly with set background in toolbar by `android:background="@color/orange_color"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/orange_color"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```